# Data-main do RequireJS não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, bower

Olá

Estou recebendo sempre a mesma mensagem ao tentar executar meu arquivo index.html que tenta recarregar o jQuery a partir do requireJS.

> /TesteRequire/jquery.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Error: Script error
>   for "jquery" http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script data-main="app.js" src="require.js"></script>
    </head>

        <script>
        require(["jquery"], function($) {
            console.log($);
        });
        </script>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "components",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery/dist/jquery",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```

Estrutura de diretórios

- TesteRequire
  - components
    - jquery
      - dist
        - jquery.js
  - .bowerrc
  - app.js
  - bower.json
  - index.html
  - require.js (biblioteca require)

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2):

O erro acontece porque o `jquery` não está carregado no momento da execução.

Conforme a documentação do [`requirejs` (em inglês)](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main):

> ...isso significa que você não pode assumir que a carga e execução do **data-main** irá ocorrer antes dos demais scripts...

e, também:

> ...se você pretende utilizar o require dentro de scripts definidos no HTML, é melhor não utilizar o `data-main`

Existem duas soluções neste caso:

---

1) Conforme a documentação, você pode carregar o script de configuração e deixá-lo como uma dependência para a carga do `jquery`:

```
<script src="/lib/require.js"></script>

<!-- Carrega a configuração separadamente, fora do data-main -->
<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
    <script>
    // === Cria a dependência ===
    require(['app.js'], function() {
        // === Executa a chamada do jquery ===
        require(["jquery"], function($) {
            console.log($);
        });
    });
 </script>
```

---

2) Colocar todo o código de configuração dentro do HTML:

```
<script>
// Configura.....
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "components",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery/dist/jquery",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});

// Executa.....
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    console.log($);
});
</script>
```